# Android : I am not able to see list of files saved using Scoped Storage in debug build

Tags: android

I am using getExternalFilesDir() method to save files in the app specific directory. I used scoped storage . It is working fine in QA build. Everything seems working, showing list of files and all. But in debug build, the file list returning empty.

Comment: Any specific OS have an issue?

Comment: check your app specific folder whether files actually exist there or not and also try to log the file path as it's debug mode you can check logcat which can help you out.

Comment: I have only OS 9 Moto G6.

Comment: It worked when I disconnected from adb.